# Template not rendering underscore error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

Hi i'm new to backbone using require and underscore. Want to render a template please correct me . Dont know where i'm going wrong.

mainParentTemplate.html

```
<div>
      manojbojja
</div>
```

mainWidgetnew.js

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone',
    'text!app/templates/main/mainParentTemplate.html',
    'masonry',
    'imagesLoaded',
    'Aviary',
    'date',
    'datetimepicker',
    'infinitescroll',
    'bootstrap'],
    function($, _, Backbone,
             MainParentViewTemplate){

    var RssParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: MainParentViewTemplate,

        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(_.template(this.template,{}));
        }
    });

    var FeedsWidget = function() {

        this.render = function(el) {
            this.view = new RssParentView({el: el});
        };

        return this;
    }

    return FeedsWidget;

});
```

main html page script

```
<div id="main-widget">
</div>

<script>
    window.init = function(){
        require(['app/mainWidgetnew'], function(FeedsWidget){

            var mainWidgetnew= new FeedsWidget();
            mainWidgetnew.render("#main-widget");
        });
    };
</script>
```

I'm getting uderscore error "undefined is not a function"

```
this.$el.html(_.template(mainParentTemplate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore's [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) function will return functions that can be evaluated for rendering.

You can do following in your render :

```
var template = _.template(this.template); 
this.$el.html(template(paramsForTemplate));
```

Where `paramsForTemplate` is optional and can be used to pass parameters to the template.